# How to extract integer or float value from a string in Python?

Tags: python, shell, numbers, extract, python-re

I have a string:

```
s = "abcd 90 96.8% ab"
```

I want to extract 90 and 96.8 from the string like this `[90, 96.8]`

I have tried doing it by regex:

```
print(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", s))
```

output: `[96.8]`

```
print(re.findall("\d+", s))
```

output: `[90, 96, 8]`

Can anyone tell me the solution which extracts int as well as a decimal from string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop like this:

```
s = "abcd 90 96.8% ab"
num = []
for n in s.split(): # For every substring in the string separated by a space
    a = ''
    for l in n: # For every character in the substring
        if l.isdigit() or l == '.': # If the character is a number or a decimal poit
            a += l
    if a:
        num.append(a)
print(num)
```

Output:

```
['90', '96.8']
```